# Leading behavior of the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\sin t}e^{-x\sin^4t}dt$ as $x\to\infty$.

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, laplace-method

> $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\sin t}e^{-x\sin^4t}dt$$

I want to apply Laplace's method. And since the maximal of $-\sin^4t$ achieves at $t=0$, the contribution to the integral is at 0, but at the same time $\sqrt{\sin t}$ attains zero. So does that mean the leading behavior of the integral is just $0$? If so, how can we rigorously(kind of) show that?

Comment: If you're interested in learning about the justifications for approximations such as these you might be interested to read the appendix of my thesis. It's intended to be an instructive introduction to the asymptotic analysis of integrals such as these. You can download it here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03387

Answer (score 2):

Near $t=0$ we have

$$
\sin^4 t \sim t^4 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sqrt{\sin t} \sim \sqrt{t},
$$

so by the Laplace method

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin t} e^{-x \sin^4 t}\,dt \sim \int_0^\infty \sqrt{t} e^{-xt^4}\,dt = \frac{1}{4} \Gamma\!\left(\frac{3}{8}\right) x^{-3/8}
$$

as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: The justification for this is standard, see any text which goes into detail on the Laplace method.